# Readymade Cocoa Spotlight UI Components

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, macos, spotlight

I'm new to developing on the Mac and am looking to implement an interface similar to Spotlight's - the main part which seems to be an expanding table/grid view.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a component Apple provides for creating something like this or is available open source else where.

Of course if not I'll just try and work something out myself but it's always worth checking!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Programming does that to me :'(

Comment: I never get so blue it fills my entire avatar ... maybe some Paxil? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New Answer (December, 2015)**

These days I'd go with a vertical stack view ( [NSStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSStackView_Class/) ).

You can use its hiding priorities to guarantee the number of results you show will fit (it'll hide those it can't). Note, it doesn't reuse views like a table view reuses cell views, so it's only appropriate for a limited number of "results" in your case, especially since it doesn't make sense to add a bunch of subviews that'll never appear. I'd go so far as to say outright you shouldn't use it for lists of things you intend to scroll (in this case, go with a table view).

The priority setting can be used to make sure your assumption of what should be "enough" results doesn't cause ugly layout issues by letting the stack view "sacrifice" the last few.

You can even emulate Spotlight's "Spotlight Preferences" entry (or a "show all" option) by adding it last and setting its priority to required (1000) so it always stays put even if result entries above it are hidden due to lack of space.

Lately all my UI designs for 10.11 (and beyond) have been making *heavy* use of them. I keep finding new ways to simplify my layouts with them. Given how lightweight they are, they should be your go-to solution *first* unless you need something more complex (Apple engineers stated in WWDC videos they're intended to be used in this way).

***Old 2011 Answer***

This is private Apple API. I don't know of any open-source initiatives that mimic it off-hand.

Were I trying to do it, I might use an NSTableView with no enclosing scroll view, no headers, two columns, right-justified lighter-colored text in the left column, the easily-googled image/text cell in the right column, with vertical grid lines turned on. The container view would observe the table view for frame changes and resize/reposition accordingly.

**Adding:** It might be a good idea also to see if the right/left justified text (or even the position of the columns) is different in languages with different sweep paths. Example: Arabic and Hebrew are read right-to-left. Better to adapt than to say "who cares" (he says flippantly while knowing full well his own apps have problems with this sort of thing :-)). You can test this by making sure such languages are installed on your computer, then switching between them and testing out Spotlight. Changing languages shouldn't pose an issue since the language switching UI doesn't rely on reading a foreign language. :-)

Comment: Right yup, I think I've settled on doing it using NSTableView. Shouldn't really be too bad judging by your summary either.